# Wrap text on custom headers in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

Is there a way to auto wrap text on colHeaders when given colWidths? It doesn't seem to work and even manually reducing the size of the columns is prohibited.

Relevant options:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: items,
    startRows: 1,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: ['aaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccc'],
    colWidths: [50,50,50]
    manualColumnResize: true,
    autoWrapRow: true
}
```

Comment: Related forum post: https://forum.handsontable.com/t/header-word-wrap/209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try add some CSS into your headers:

```
.handsontable table thead th {
  white-space: pre-line;
  max-width: /* enter here your max header width */
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: For anyone using this hack, there's one issue. Because Handsontable wasn't written to support it, the overlay frozen headers will go out of whack if the headers are taller than 1 cell in height. Some extra hacking is needed to correct this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following CSS:

```
.handsontable th {
    white-space: normal!important;
}
```

Demo and source: http://jsfiddle.net/cyancscoutrfp/hqLbg3rt/

Comment: Code snippetts
<style>
    .handsontable th {
        white-space: normal !important;
    }
</style>
<fieldset>
      <div id="notesTblDiv" class="hot handsontable htColumnHeaders"></div>
</fieldset>
var notesElement = document.querySelector('#notesTblDiv');
var notesTbl = new Handsontable(notesElement, notesSettings);